# how to reference module in java

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I have project in java that is contain two module.

First module is spring boot and my controller in this module and i call it Host Api.

Second module is maven module  and call it command layer and all common model in this module.

My problem is here when is want to reference between two module (it mean my controller use common model) my project run fine but when i `clean compile install` whit maven give me an error

This error show when `c:\userd\.m2\repository\project name` is empty

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12\bin\java.exe" -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=C:\Users\m.familsahraei\Desktop\Test\Api "-Dmaven.home=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1\plugins\maven\lib\maven3" "-Dclassworlds.conf=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\bin\m2.conf" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=2356:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar" org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version2019.1 clean compile install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building test 0.0.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/command/commandartifact/0.0.1/commandartifact-0.0.1.pom
[WARNING] The POM for command:commandartifact:jar:0.0.1 is missing, no dependency information available
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/command/commandartifact/0.0.1/commandartifact-0.0.1.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.364 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-06-26T09:41:00+04:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 18M/64M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project test: Could not resolve dependencies for project api:test:jar:0.0.1: Could not find artifact command:commandartifact:jar:0.0.1 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException

Process finished with exit code 1
```

And when i `clean compile install` again give me differ error

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12\bin\java.exe" -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:2349,suspend=y,server=n -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=C:\Users\m.familsahraei\Desktop\Test\Api "-Dmaven.home=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1\plugins\maven\lib\maven3" "-Dclassworlds.conf=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\bin\m2.conf" -javaagent:C:\Users\m.familsahraei\.IntelliJIdea2019.1\system\captureAgent\debugger-agent.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1\lib\idea_rt.jar" org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version2019.1 clean compile install
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:2349', transport: 'socket'
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Sharing is only supported for boot loader classes because bootstrap classpath has been appended
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building test 0.0.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for command:commandartifact:jar:0.0.1 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.374 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-06-26T09:39:16+04:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/57M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:2349', transport: 'socket'
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project test: Could not resolve dependencies for project api:test:jar:0.0.1: Failure to find command:commandartifact:jar:0.0.1 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException

Process finished with exit code 1
```

This is my Host Api pom file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>api</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <name>test</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>12</java.version>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>command</groupId>
            <artifactId>commandartifact</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>




    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And my Command pom file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>command</groupId>
    <artifactId>commandartifact</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>


</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have execute `mvn install` also for the commandartifact project to install it into the local maven repository.